# macOS ssh ignoring UserKnownHostsFile option

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I'm frequently sshing to virtual machines through a jump host that have ephemeral IP addresses and often have changing ssh keys. I don't want to be prompted if the ssh key changes nor prompted to accept the ssh key.

I've read about the StrictHostKeyChecking and UserKnownHostsFile options, but they don't seem to have any effect.When passing the UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null on the command line, the ssh host key always gets added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts (I've got dozens of entries now) and I always get prompted to accept the ssh key.

I don't want this level of non-checking to be global, for security reasons, just for this connection that I've got scripted in a bash file.

Here's the ssh command I'm using:

```
ssh  -o 'ConnectTimeout=10' \
     -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
     -o 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' \
     -o 'CheckHostIP=no' \
     -i ~/.ssh/my_ident \
     "username@ip" \
     -J "username@jump"
```

Also, in case the '=' portion is the problem, I've tried this but still get the same result:

```
ssh  -o 'ConnectTimeout 10' \
     -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' \
     -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' \
     -o 'CheckHostIP no' \
     -i ~/.ssh/my_ident \
     "username@ip" \
     -J "username@jump"
```

I'm on macOS 10.14.4 using OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

Any idea why the -o parameters are getting ignored - or not doing what I want?

Comment: I have the same issue and was suspecting the "brew" shipped version of ssh client.  But both macOS version as well as the brew version seems to be exhibiting this behavior, which is annoying.
`$ /usr/bin/ssh -V`
`OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`

`$ /usr/local/bin/ssh -V`
`OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019`

Comment: In my knowledge the best option you got left is to use a config file inside your local .ssh folder.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to MacOS. The parameters like `StrictHostKeyChecking`, `UserKnownHostsFile` and `CheckHostIP` are only related to the target host that you're connecting to. In your case, it's `ip`. They have no effect on the `jump` host specified as part of the `-J` argument.

I believe there's no way to specify these settings for the jump host in the command line. But you could add those parameters to your `~/.ssh/config` file, something like this:

```
Host jump
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    CheckHostIP no
```